# SFDX plugin to retrieve metadata from org

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, sfdx-plugin

I am looking for a SFDX plugin which can retrieve all the metadata available in an org. In most of the approaches, I see that you need to create package.xml first, and then issue a retrieve call. Is there any other way so that I don't have to create package.xml?

Or is there any other plugin which can create package.xml by looking at an org?

And let's say if the count of metadata files is more than 10000 in an org, then how would I be able to get the remaining metadata files?

Answer (score 1):

You can [turn on tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_tracking.htm) for sandboxes and then simply use `sfdx force:source:pull` to retrieve all the retrievable metadata on the org to your local file system.

Answer (score 1):

@snl,

I'm working on a plugin for sfdx /sf that will do some of this.

https://github.com/codefriar/cf-sfdx-plugin.git

it's still a work in progress, and isn't published so you'll have to install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

What I use is [Salesforce Package.xml Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator). Once you are connected to the Org in VS code you can open the plugin with ctrl + shift + P. Select all metadata types in the drop-down and click update Package.xml or copy it. Then a simple retrieve on the package.xml should do it.

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer in this blog post.
https://www.pablogonzalez.io/how-to-retrieve-your-entire-salesforce-metadata-with-2-commands/

I was not aware that we can get the package.xml file having all the metadata in an org.

And the most funny thing: who downvoted my question?